# How do I generate a random hour slot between two time periods in Excel?

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

Trying to generate a start time for a random hour slot between two time periods in Excel. 
For example, if the time period is between 06:48 and 09:36, the start time generated could be any value between 06:48 and 08:36 (to allow for the hour slot).

I will need this formula to apply to lots of different periods of time so the easier the formula is to manipulate the better.

Comment: Hi Joe, you've explained the problem well. Perhaps you could also include anything you've tried so that we can give you more specific pointers or at least explain to you why your method isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```
=A2+RANDBETWEEN(0,INT((B2-A2)*24))/24
```

[image]

---

*Some explanation*

1. `B2-A2` returns some fraction, between 0 and 1, of the 24 hour day
2. `(B2-A2)*24` returns the decimal number of hours between 0 and 24
3. `INT((B2-A2)*24))` rounds the decimal *down* to the nearest hour, e.g. 2 in your example
4. `RANDBETWEEN(0,2)` picks a random number between 0 and 2
5. This random number can be divided by 24 and added to your start time to give a new start time

Make sure your cell `C2` (in my example) is formatted in the same way as `A2` and `B2` otherwise your result will just look like some number between 0 and 1

**Update**

This will give you a random minute between 06:48 and 08:36 (as per your example):

```
=A2+RANDBETWEEN(0,INT((B2-A2-1/24)*24*60))/(24*60)
```

Comment: Hi Callum, thanks a lot for your help. This is great however not quite what I'm after. I require a completely random time, including the minutes part of the value, that is between the range but is at least an hour from the upper range. 
So in the example above, the random time generated could be 07:12, 08:25, 08:01, 06:59 etc.. The limit would be 08:36 as that is an hour from the upper range (09:36). 

I realise this is a difficult ask so please don't stress too much, there is always random number generator websites online...

Comment: @Joe DS Thanks for clarifying, I've updated my answer. If you find it works please accept the answer using the tick mark on the left :)